# Wpf Button content not showing for specific buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, imagebutton

My program shows two live video feeds and has buttons to rotate, flip, and invert each feed separately. Each set of buttons is in its own stack panel above the feed. My XAML references some png images which I am using as icons, and the `content` property of each button is an image.

I created one panel first and they all functioned how I intended, however after copying the XAML into the other set of buttons, the new set works and the old set with *unchanged code* no longer has the icons:

[image: Buttons on left have icon missing]

The invert button at the end works propely, however it is a `ToggleButton` and not a `Button`.

What is wrong?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MLD_UI_1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MLD_UI_1" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" MinHeight="700" Width="525" MinWidth="1050">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource MainBackgroundBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border BorderThickness="2 2 1 2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                Background="{StaticResource UvGradientBrush}"
                CornerRadius="5 0 0 5"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="1 2 2 2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                Background="{StaticResource IrGradientBrush}"
                CornerRadius="0 5 5 0"/>

        <Border BorderThickness="2 2 1 2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                Background="{StaticResource GradientBrush}"
                CornerRadius="5 0 0 5">
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="1 2 2 2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
                Background="{StaticResource GradientBrush}"
                CornerRadius="0 5 5 0"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="10 0 10 0">
            <TextBlock Text="UV"
                       FontFamily="Tahoma"
                       Foreground="White"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"/>
            <Button x:Name="AnticlockwiseBtn"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource ARotateImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="AnticlockwiseBtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="ClockwiseBtn"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource RotateImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="ClockwiseBtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="HorizontalBtn"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource HFlipImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="HorizontalBtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="VerticalBtn"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource VFlipImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="VerticalBtn_Click"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="InvertBtn"
                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="InvertBtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="10 0 10 0">
            <TextBlock Text="IR"
                       FontFamily="Tahoma"
                       Foreground="White"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20"/>
            <Button x:Name="AnticlockwiseBtnR"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource ARotateImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="AnticlockwiseBtnR_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="ClockwiseBtnR"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource RotateImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="ClockwiseBtnR_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="HorizontalBtnR"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource HFlipImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="HorizontalBtnR_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="VerticalBtnR"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Content="{StaticResource VFlipImg}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="VerticalBtnR_Click"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="InvertBtnR"
                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"
                    Height="15"
                    Width="15"
                    Click="InvertBtnR_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Image x:Name="imagePane1"
               Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="2 2 2 2"/>
        <Image x:Name="imagePane2"
               Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="2 2 2 2"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Orientation="Vertical">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">

            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MLD_UI_1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MLD_UI_1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MLD_UI_1">
            <!--  Define the basic colours  -->
            <Color x:Key="FandFMainColour">#FF228B22</Color>
            <Color x:Key="FandFSecondaryColour">#FF315531</Color>
            <Color x:Key="FandFGrey">#FF696969</Color>
            <Color x:Key="FandFWhite">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
            <Color x:Key="FandFBlack">#FF000000</Color>
            <!--  Define the basic brushes that use the colours  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FandFBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="{StaticResource FandFMainColour}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FF0023BF" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBackgroundBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFFFFFE1" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainBackgroundBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="{StaticResource FandFGrey}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderHighlightBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFFF0000" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryBorderHighlightBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFFFFF00" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FF000000" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TertiaryBackgroundBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryBackgroundBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFD3D3D3" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrighterFandFBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="Lime" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeBrush"
                     RenderOptions.CachingHint="Cache"
                     RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                     Color="#FFFF8000" />
            <!--  Define a basic gradient that goes from the light green to the dark green  -->
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradientBrush"
                                 StartPoint="0.5,0"
                                 EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                      Color="{StaticResource FandFMainColour}" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                      Color="{StaticResource FandFSecondaryColour}" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <!--  Gradient brush for UV toolbar background  -->
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="UvGradientBrush"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0"
                         EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                      Color="#7f4dff" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                      Color="#240080" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <!--  Gradient brush for IR toolbar background  -->
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="IrGradientBrush"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0"
                         EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0"
                      Color="#db2424" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1"
                      Color="#420b0b" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <!--  The global font settings  -->
            <FontFamily x:Key="NormalFontFamily">Verdana</FontFamily>
            <FontFamily x:Key="HeaderFontFamily">Tahoma</FontFamily>
            <!--  Define the basic geometries  -->
            <Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z</Geometry>
            <Geometry x:Key="TickShapeGeometry">M 2,4 C 2,4 3,5 5,13 C 5,13 5,3 12,0</Geometry>
            <Geometry x:Key="ExpanderArrowGeometry">M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 8,1.5</Geometry>
            <!--  A style for all tool tips  -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource GradientBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
                Value="600" />
                <Setter Property="Placement"
                Value="Mouse" />
                <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding"
                Value="True" />
            </Style>
            <!-- A style for all buttons -->
            <Style TargetType="Button"
                   x:Key="ButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Verdana"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <!-- Style for ToggleButtons -->
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
                   x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="HotPink"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content"
                                Value="{StaticResource InvImg2}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="images/inverted.png"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="images/invert.png"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <!-- Load button icons as resources -->
            <Image x:Key="HFlipImg" Source="images/horizontal flip.png"/>
            <Image x:Key="VFlipImg" Source="images/vertical flip.png"/>
            <Image x:Key="RotateImg" Source="images/clockwise rotate.png"/>
            <Image x:Key="ARotateImg" Source="images/anticlockwise rotate.png"/>
            <Image x:Key="InvImg" Source="images/invert.png"/>
            <Image x:Key="InvImg2" Source="images/inverted.png"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: add `x:Shared="False"` on `Image` resources

Comment: I can't believe I missed that question! It's so simple!